# PSTricks with TeXworks?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, texworks

I've read a lot instructions online for compiling a document using PSTricks but I don't understand any of them. I'm used to using TeXworks (and TeXshop on OSX) [reverse phone lookup](https://reversephonelookup.onl/) to compile directly to PDF using PDFLaTeX. It seems like that won't work so [nba reddit](https://curated.onl/nba-reddit/) I need to do something to convert to PS first. All the instructions I see use phrases like "just point TeXworks at..." and "invoke [suchandsuch]" but I don't know enough to make that happen [pcpartpicker](https://pcbuilder.onl/pcpartpicker/) I'm competent at writing code, and have used tikz successfully, but I don't understand enough about how compilation works to use a package that depends on PSTricks.

Could someone please give me a hand going from a .tex file that uses PSTricks to a PDF? I'm on Windows 10. Thanks so much.

Oh, and I'm not including a minimum working example. I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: You need to run `latex myfile.tex` then `dvips myfile.dvi` and finally `ps2pdf myfile.ps`. You can do this in a terminal (just cd into the directory with your files and then type the commands). Alternatively, there will be a way to tell your IDE to run these commands; just dig around in the menus until you find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest is to compile with `xelatex`. Other than that, you may compile directly with `pdflatex` if you load `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* `pstricks`) and add the compiler switch `--shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX).